# Google maps-places initialize is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use googles api places for address autocomplete, and it keeps telling me initialize is not a function. I have a call back in my api link called initialize but it doesnt seem to work. here is my code so far

my api link with initialize callback function

```
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
       key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize">
```

my intialize() function

```
      function initialize(){

        var autocomplete;
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById(searchInput)), {
            types: ['geocode'],
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var near_place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });
    }
```

not sure why I keeps telling me initialize is not a function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maps script is not loaded before you custom script?

Comment: @zmii I tried placing the link at the bottom of the body tag but it still doesnt work. I am not sure what you mean by script is not loaded before custom script.